# Read files from sharepoint using Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am trying to read files from sharepoint using Office365-REST-Python-Client and I am getting the error as below.
I have ~13K+ folders and there are files within each folder. Google says that the number of folder should be less than 5k, so does it mean I need to iterate? Has any one done this? Any reference please?

```
ClientRequestException: ('-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException', 'The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.', "500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url
```